# Will the newer of these processors be faster?

Tags: performance, cpu, comparison

Here is a comparison of the processor in our current laptop, and a new laptop I'm considering buying:

http://ark.intel.com/Compare.aspx?ids=27231,42791,

Although the newer one is 1.3 (as opposed to our current 1.6), is it actually likely to be (or more accurately "feel") faster than the existing one?

I'm not a newbie, and I've looked at the other specs for the machines - the newer machine has a faster disk and FSB, as well has having more memory.  The only intensive thing I can think it'll be used for is flash-based games.

Comment: Usually even more intensive than flash-based games is HD Streaming content. But even my macbook with a 2 GHz Core 2 Duo had trouble with 720p content on Hulu, although I can't see that 720p content exists anymore on there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for the 1.3Ghz chip. It has more L2 cache, faster FSB, and numerous important features not supported by the other chip which outweigh the 300mhz clock difference (ie. Intel VT for running virtual machines - still good to have around even if you're playing flash games). The difference won't be drastic, but still noticeable.